# Librosa and matplotlib (with PyQt5) getting error

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, librosa

I'm trying to make a waveform of a song. And display it in both a matplotlib window wrapped by PyQt, but i keep encountering an error:

```
 RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure
```

This occurs at when i try to do:

```
self.axes.add_collection(col)
```

Unlike when i import pyplot, it's not added to the plot by itself when just calling `waveform`. So that's the problem, and using the add_collection, the only way i could google my way to, is not working well for me.

Additional information, `col` is a `PolyCollection`.

This is the code full code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import librosa.display
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import os
import random


class WaveForm(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        dir_path = 'D:\\Musikk\\DLs\\'
        dir_content = os.listdir(dir_path)
        file = os.path.join(dir_path, random.choice(dir_content))
        # Replace file with any song you may have.
        y, sr = librosa.load(file, mono=False, duration=None)
        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 2))

        super().__init__(fig)

        col = librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr=sr)

        self.axes = fig.gca()
        self.axes.add_collection(col)

        self.draw()
        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = WaveForm()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by making setting waveplot take a keyword argument called ax, where you give it the axes. You do not need to store the col variable, nor add_collection on it.

```
librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr=sr, ax=self.axes)
```